# How to pass javascript dynamic variable to a function in another javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScripts. from first JavaScript I want to call a function in other JavaScript like example below:

```
jwplayer().load({file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4'})
```

The above call to jwplayer function works fine but i want to load dynamic media URLs to jwplayer function using variable URL that already holds dynamic value. I tried the following but it never passes the dynamic media URL to jwplayer function!could you guys tell me what i am doing wrong ? the alert shows the URL value which proves that URL is okay but it never passes it to player!

```
....
alert('' + url);
jwplayer().load({file: '+ url'});
```

this second JavaScript:

```
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
        'flashplayer': './player.swf',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '470',
        'height': '320'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried: jwplayer().load({file: url}); instead?

Comment: There's only one JavaScript.  It's a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

you're url in `jwplayer().load({file: '+ url'});` is being read as a string, not a variable. it should be:

```
jwplayer().load({file: url});
```

Comment: Many Many thanks i was spending past 30 min to find out what i am doing wrong!It worked like perfectly!